# I am seen in darkness and in light, What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am seen in darkness and in light,
>
> I am calm yet tend to fright.
>
> I can be quiet, I can be loud,
>
> I hide in shame, yet am so proud.
>
> I can be different, but still the same,
>
> I am straightforward yet am playing games.
>
> You can easily find me,
>
> but you'd have to look and see.
>
> I am found everywhere I know,
>
> but why is it sometimes not so?
>
> So many things that I can make,
>
> but how many tries will it take?

**What am I?**

Comment: you are ... a riddle xD

Comment: but how many tries will it take? tries to do what?

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal read last 2 lines in continuation

Comment: At this point, this might generate number of answers I guess.

Comment: it's a cockroach

Comment: @Kavin- It can be a cricket as well. Or a mosquito etc

Comment: How did this get 19 upvotes?  It's a hugely generic description that could apply to almost anything.  The lines as written don't even seem to apply to the accepted answer as well as they do to other answers.  It's no wonder there are 12 different answers posted!

Comment: People who write riddles in rhyming couplets really need to learn about [poetic meter](http://literarydevices.net/meter/).  Or at the very, very least, about counting syllables.  :)

Comment: But the accepted answer is the only one that spotted "Style" and properly presented it as a sentence.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Because HNQ.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

ANSWER:

> MATCH

I am seen in darkness and in light,

> Can be see by day and by night (when lit)

I am calm yet tend to fright.

> Normally inert but on striking can frighten people.

I can be quiet, I can be loud,

> Stiking can be noisy or quiet

I hide in shame, yet am so proud.

> Normally concealed in a box unless lit (proud)

I can be different, but still the same,

> Different types of matches exist. Also c.f. other definition of match e.g.  'perfect match' (regarding "same" clue).

I am straightforward yet am playing games.

> c.f. yet another definition of "match" e.g. 'soccer match'.

you can easily find me,

> Quite common

but you'd have to look and see.

> Can be small

I am found everywhere I know,

> Ubiquitous technology

but why is it sometimes not so?

> Style.

So many things that I can make,

> You can build things using matchsticks :D

but how many tries will it take?

> Sometimes it takes many attempts to light a match

Comment: Smart! This should be it. +1

Answer (score 5):

ANSWER:

> The moon

I am seen in darkness and in light,

> Can see it in the day sometimes, most of the time at night

I am calm yet tend to fright.

> The moon is a symbol of peacefulness, yet it is also quite spooky when framed in such a way (think werewolves)

I can be quiet, I can be loud,

> quiet / loud can be terms for how bright an object it. And the moon can be barely visible during the day (quiet), and in contrast to the night sky, very bright (loud)

I hide in shame, yet am so proud.

> the moon hides behind the earth half sometimes

I can be different, but still the same,

> different phases of the moon make it look different, but the moon itself never changes.

I am straightforward yet am playing games.

> not really sure about this

you can easily find me,

> yep

but you'd have to look and see.

> yep

I am found everywhere I know,

> if the moon was alive, it would know itself as a world/planet ('world' is sometimes used in language as a synonym for 'all' ex: "you mean the world to me" / "You mean everything to me") and so it would be found everywhere it looks.

but why is it sometimes not so?

> because of the orbit of the moon, it is hidden from us sometimes behind the earth

So many things that I can make,

> the moon makes the oceans tidal, it makes a great piece of art

but how many tries will it take?

> this could be a reference to how many times it took to get to the moon

Comment: Awesome answer. +1. Really love the spooky and calm part :)

Answer (score 3):

Is it -

> A Theatre

I am seen in darkness and in light,

> Can be seen in darkness and full lights

I am calm yet tend to fright.

> Theatres are calm but can fright people with stage fright.

I can be quiet, I can be loud,

> Quieter when nothing is played. Loud during a play/movie.

I hide in shame, yet am so proud.

> Its hidden behind a curtain but people/actors are proud once the curtains are moved.

I can be different, but still the same,

> Theatres can be of different shapes and sizes but do the same thing.

I am straitforward yet am playing games.

> Probably its located straight forward in front of our eyes and plays are performed on it or games are broadcasted on it.

you can easily find me,

> Easily found.

but you'd have to look and see.

> We have to look at it and watch the things played.

I am found every where I know,

> Same as above

but why is it sometimes not so?

> Probably they are not found in some schools and colleges.

so many things that I can make,

> Can play movies, plays, shows etc

but how many tries will it take?

> Takes various tries to perform the final event.

Answer (score 3):

It might be a

> Shadow

I am seen in darkness and in light,

> Darkness is nothing but shadow, and every light casts one.

I am calm yet tend to fright.

> People are scared of shadows

I can be quiet, I can be loud,

> Not sure about this one... perhaps in movies, where scary shadows are accompanied by scare chords?

I hide in shame, yet am so proud.

> Thieves and criminals are often said to lurk in shadows...

I can be different, but still the same,

> Same outline, but two-dimensional

I am straightforward yet am playing games.

> Making shadow puppets

you can easily find me,
but you'd have to look and see.

> Again, everything casts a shadow

I am found everywhere I know,
but why is it sometimes not so?

> If you use a flashlight to look for a shadow, you'll never find it.

So many things that I can make,
but how many tries will it take?

> Making shadow puppets is hard.

Answer (score 3):

ANSWER:

> COMPUTER

I am seen in darkness and in light,

> literally, can be seen in dark/light

I am calm yet tend to fright.

> just sits there but frightens novices

I can be quiet, I can be loud,

> adjustable volume

I hide in shame, yet am so proud.

> *not sure*

I can be different, but still the same,

> multi-functional

I am straightforward yet am playing games.

> operates on logic; can play various games on it

you can easily find me,

> easily identifiable; conspicuous

but you'd have to look and see.

> have to interact with it to get information

I am found everywhere I know,

> they are globally ubiquitous

but why is it sometimes not so?

> obscure subset of people wishes to stay off the grid

So many things that I can make,

> programs can be written to make it do anything

but how many tries will it take?

> depending on complexity, from one time to unknown

Answer (score 2):

I think you are

> a human heart

I am seen in darkness and in light

> In light during an operation. Darkness via one of those machines which hospitals have.

I am calm yet tend to fright.

> Explanatory.

I can be quiet, I can be loud.

> When you're scared your heart beats louder.

I hide in shame, yet am so proud.

> It's common saying that your heart feels (technically it doesn't but still). At times you feel good about yourself and at times the it's the other way around.

I can be different, but still the same,

> Different health conditions but same functionality.

I am straightforward yet am playing games.

> Nothing solid but here goes. Your heart wants to do things that are fun and wants to avoid work?

you can easily find me,

> You just have to look within. (probably finding what you love)

but you'd have to look and see.

> You have to look within :)

I am found every where I know,

> Hearts are pretty common. Might also be referring to love :)

but why is it sometimes not so?

> People being greedy, cruel or mean?

so many things that I can make,

> If you're heart is set to something, you can do so many wonderful things.

but how many tries will it take?

> Not quitting and sticking to your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Its'a

> Cockroach

I am seen in darkness and in light,

> It can be see in day and night

I am calm yet tend to fright.

> It's calm but people afraid of it

I can be quiet, I can be loud,

> It will make sounds sometimes in night

I hide in shame, yet am so proud.

> If you touch it, it will run and hide.

I can be different, but still the same,

> Different types of breeds.

I am straightforward yet am playing games.

> People Play with it to afraid others

you can easily find me,

> Easily find in garbges

but you'd have to look and see.

> But need to look clearly

I am found everywhere I know,

> Found everywhere in home

but why is it sometimes not so?

> Sometimes not if we use cockroach killers

So many things that I can make,

> So many diseases

but how many tries will it take?

> killing on so many tries, but it keeps escaping.

Comment: Why not cricket? :D

Comment: @Techidiot How i forget that? :))

Comment: Can be any nocturnal insect found in home

Answer (score 1):

> Wax?

I am seen in darkness and in light,

> Candle

I am calm yet tend to fright.

> Flame

I can be quiet, I can be loud,

I hide in shame, yet am so proud.

> Melted but still burns

I can be different, but still the same,

> Can take any shape

I am straightforward yet am playing games.

you can easily find me,

but you'd have to look and see.

I am found everywhere I know,

but why is it sometimes not so?

So many things that I can make,

but how many tries will it take?

Comment: You could provide some explanation as to why you think, this should be the answer. Riddles generally require a more comprehensive explanation

Answer (score 1):

You are a

> language

I am seen in darkness and in light,

> Language can be heard in light and darkness

I am calm yet tend to fright.

> Words of the language form stories that can be calm or frightening

I can be quiet, I can be loud,

> You can speak quietly or scream loudly

I hide in shame, yet am so proud.

> Language can describe many emotions, shame and pride included

I can be different, but still the same,

> There are many languages that have different words for the same things

I am straightforward yet am playing games.

> You can speak openly, or in riddles :)

you can easily find me,

> obviously

but you'd have to look and see.

> and check out some words in dictionary?

I am found everywhere I know,

> All people use some language

but why is it sometimes not so?

> But sometimes there is no one to speak (i.e. desert)

So many things that I can make,

> You can write a novel, describe your invention, write a computer program (programming languages!)...

but how many tries will it take?

> But it's not always easy

Answer (score 1):

My answer is:

> Tongue

Because

> It can be calm or it can be loud. It lives in light (open mouth) and dark (closed mouth). It can play games with its words.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Fear

I am seen in darkness and in light,

> ! Fear can be sensed or felt in light and darkness
>   I am calm yet tend to fright.
>
> !  Fear itself is void but is frightening
>   I can be quiet, I can be loud,
>
> !  When someone fears, he can be quiet or loud
>   I hide in shame, yet am so proud.
>
> !  Fearing is an act of cowards but it wins humans
>   I can be different, but still the same,
>   I am straightforward yet am playing games.
>   .
>   .
>   .

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> memories?

I am calm yet tend to fright.

> Memory can be calm, but many can cause you anxiety

I can be quiet, I can be loud,

> Can be quiet at times, other times nostalgia can make memory very "loud"

I hide in shame, yet am so proud.

> You want to forget what you're ashamed of, want to remember what makes you proud.

I can be different, but still the same,

> Different people can have different memories of the same thing

I am straightforward yet am playing games.

> Memories can wander from one thing to another

you can easily find me,

> Always making them

but you'd have to look and see.

> Have to stop and think

I am found everywhere I know,

> You have memories of everywhere you know

but why is it sometimes not so?

> Except sometimes you can't remember something you need

So many things that I can make,

> We make memories all the time

but how many tries will it take?

> Sometimes it takes a while to commit something to memory

Comment: I recommend that you add an explanation for each line instead of just listing the lines of the poem

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE!  I'll echo what Beastly Gerbil said (see, for example, the other answers on this puzzle), and also note that you might want to look at the other answers before adding your own: this puzzle has already been successfully answered.

Comment: I did not see that it was successfully answered -- how can you tell?

Comment: @JaySpell if the answer has a green tick next to it it is correct.